# How many non-overlapping circles can you fit into an area?

Tags: combinatorics, circles, packing-problem

Say you have an area, let's use a circle, and you want to cover it with circular objects (coins for example). How many coins can fit completely into this area without overlaps or deformation the coins. All the coins are the same size.

I've noticed there are two ways for the coins to tessellate:

- in a square pattern with coins being placed with their centers at the intersection of grid lines.
- in a triangular pattern where coins are placed with their centers at the vertices of a triangle. Like:

  [image: example]

Comment: There is no simple answer for arbitrary areas. See for example [Circle packing in a square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_square).

Comment: Two good sources for the best known configurations of this sort of problem are [Erich's packing center](http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/packing.html) and [packomania](http://www.packomania.com/). Enjoy them.

Comment: Ummm... depends on the shape, don't you think?

Comment: Erich Friedman has retired and his packing center has moved to
https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The keyword of this subject is "circle packing". See for instance https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing.

The hexagonal packing is the densest possible.

Comment: `hexagonal packing is the densest possible` That's only true for the entire infinite plane.